# Is it possible to use HTTP byte ranges using curlpp

Tags: c++

Is it possible to get http byte ranges when using curlpp library in c++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 request.setOpt(new curlpp::options::Range(range));
```

where range is the byte range. for eg. 100-200